# Fixing result of Double.parseDouble is ignored error message

Tags: java

I have a utility class that checks to see if isNumeric or not by doing the following:

```
public static boolean isNumeric(String text) {
    try {
        Double.parseDouble(text);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

IntelliJ returns the following error:

> Warning:(30, 20) Result of 'Double.parseDouble()' is ignored

How can I refactor my code to avoid this error message? I don't need the result of `Double.parseDouble()` to do anything and I don't want to also suppress the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With mine , i don't have any mistakes ,

```
 public boolean isNumber() {
    try {
        return !Double.isNaN(Double.parseDouble(this.answer));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Not a Number");
        return false;
    }
}
```

The method Double.isNaN(Your answer) makes the trick and is better than a SuppressWarning i think ;)

Comment: what does `return !Double.isNaN(Double.parseDouble(text));` do?

Comment: Double.isNaN(text) return true if the text is a double or false if not . Check the method on the javadoc :)

Answer (score 2):

Use a `@SuppressWarnings` annotation on the method or the entire class:

```
@SuppressWarnings("UnusedReturnValue")
```

Or even better, don't reinvent the wheel and use the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102891/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-numeric-in-java) instead!